# Error while running JSGFDemo from Sphinx4

Tags: java, cmusphinx

I'm trying to run JSGFDemo from sphinx4 demos. I followed these steps from terminal:

1. cd /Users/username/sphinx4-1.0beta6
2. java -mx200m -jar bin/JSGFDemo.jar

But I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at edu.cmu.sphinx.demo.jsapi.jsgf.JSGFDemo.<init>(JSGFDemo.java:77)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.demo.jsapi.jsgf.JSGFDemo.main(JSGFDemo.java:244)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - package javax.speech does not exist
at com.sun.speech.engine.BaseEngine.<clinit>(BaseEngine.java:13)
... 2 more
```

line 77 is:

```
jsapiRecognizer = new BaseRecognizer(jsgfGrammar.getGrammarManager());
```

I've already search about the problem and all what I find is ppl using IDE rather than command line, also I already run jsapi.sh.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

JSGF demo has nothing important

Use latest and updated sphinx4 code for the best accuracy:

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4

You can download it here:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/sphinx4/5%20prealpha/